# How do I fix my problem with hostnamectl command. It cannot connect to dbus

Tags: debian, systemd, hostname, d-bus

I am running Debian 9.4. `hostname` works.

```
$ sudo strace -f hostnamectl
...snipped...
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket"}, 33) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...

Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory
```

UPDATE: here are more information:

```
$ sudo systemctl status dbus.service dbus.socket
Unit dbus.service could not be found.
Unit dbus.socket could not be found.

$ ps -p 1 
PID TTY          TIME CMD
1   ?        00:00:47 systemd

$ sudo systemctl list-unit-files --state=running
0 unit files listed.

$ sudo systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled
...snipped...
26 unit files listed.
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting dbus

Answer (score 14):

It looks like **dbus** package is missing.

Check if dbus package is installed or not using below command:

```
$ sudo dpkg -l | grep dbus
ii  dbus                           1.10.26-0+deb9u1                        amd64        simple interprocess messaging system (daemon and utilities)
ii  libdbus-1-3:amd64              1.10.26-0+deb9u1                        amd64        simple interprocess messaging system (library)
```

If **dbus** package is installed you will get output as above.

If output is blank then **dbus** package is missing. You can install the package using below command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dbus
```

After installing the package you can check the status:

```
$ sudo systemctl status dbus.service dbus.socket
● dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dbus.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-09-07 23:39:14 EDT; 10s ago
     Docs: man:dbus-daemon(1)
 Main PID: 451 (dbus-daemon)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dbus.service
           └─451 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation

● dbus.socket - D-Bus System Message Bus Socket
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dbus.socket; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-09-07 23:39:14 EDT; 10s ago
   Listen: /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket (Stream)
```

Comment: i had same issue with hotnamectl, i also needed to install dbus.  Why was it missing in the first place is a better question.  Can some kind of update cause that?  wierd.

Comment: dbus is non-essential service so depending on your setup, it may not have been installed. Anything that needs it should install it as a dependency. IMO systemd hostnamectl should ideally fallback to gathering the info in an alternate way if dbus is not available or at least give a better error message to make it clear that it doesn't work without dbus.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by using these commands, in centos7/8 containers, ubuntu containers also :

```
dbus-uuidgen > /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
mkdir -p /var/run/dbus
dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf --print-address
```

but then hit another error related to dbus socket refused connection. Will Keep posted if i progress.