# hostnamectl command causes Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory

Tags: terminal, hostname, d-bus, windows-subsystem-for-linux, unix-sockets

I'm following this guide and I'm running into issues.
https://www.tecmint.com/initial-ubuntu-server-setup-guide/

I am trying to create a linux machine in Ubuntu in wsl2 and then rename it using `hostnamectl` but have the error

```
Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory
```

I have tried to follow these solutions.

This solution suggested installing a package which I did.
[How do I fix my problem with hostnamectl command. It cannot connect to dbus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467618/how-do-i-fix-my-problem-with-hostnamectl-command-it-cannot-connect-to-dbus)

```
xuhu55@LAPTOP-DUPSMABG:/usr/share$ sudo dpkg -l | grep dbus
[sudo] password for xuhu55:
ii  at-spi2-core                   2.28.0-1                           amd64        Assistive Technology Service Provider Interface (dbus core)
ii  dbus                           1.12.2-1ubuntu1.2                  amd64        simple interprocess messaging system (daemon and utilities)
ii  libdbus-1-3:amd64              1.12.2-1ubuntu1.2                  amd64        simple interprocess messaging system (library)
ii  python-dbus                    1.2.6-1                            amd64        simple interprocess messaging system (Python interface)
ii  python3-dbus                   1.2.6-1                            amd64        simple interprocess messaging system (Python 3 interface)
xuhu55@LAPTOP-DUPSMABG:/usr/share$ sudo apt-get install dbus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
dbus is already the newest version (1.12.2-1ubuntu1.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 381 not upgraded
```

This other solution involved using `strace` which unfortunately showed that my problem was not a symlink problem that the other solution could have solved.

[hostnamectl shows error: "Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560859/hostnamectl-shows-error-failed-to-create-bus-connection-no-such-file-or-direc)

```
xuhu55@LAPTOP-DUPSMABG:/usr/share$ strace hostnamectl
execve("/usr/bin/hostnamectl", ["hostnamectl"], 0x7ffff119f3f0 /* 20 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x562bdd747000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/systemd/tls/x86_64/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/systemd/tls/x86_64/x86_64", 0x7fffde186d70) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/systemd/tls/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

...

```
stat("/lib/systemd", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=39569, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 39569, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb215297000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260\34\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2030544, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb215295000
mmap(NULL, 4131552, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb214c89000
mprotect(0x7fb214e70000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb215070000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7fb215070000
mmap(0x7fb215076000, 15072, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb215076000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-237.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@|\3\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2355440, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4457440, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb214848000
mprotect(0x7fb2149fd000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb214bfc000, 569344, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b4000) = 0x7fb214bfc000
mmap(0x7fb214c87000, 5088, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb214c87000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\"\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=31680, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2128864, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb214640000
mprotect(0x7fb214647000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb214846000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7fb214846000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20\30\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=22768, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2117976, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb21443a000
mprotect(0x7fb21443e000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb21463e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x4000) = 0x7fb21463e000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\33\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=31232, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2126336, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb214232000
mprotect(0x7fb214239000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb214438000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7fb214438000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcryptsetup.so.12", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0``\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=310040, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2405352, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb213fe6000
mprotect(0x7fb21402f000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb21422f000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x49000) = 0x7fb21422f000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\274\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1155768, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb215293000
mmap(NULL, 3252232, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb213ccb000
mprotect(0x7fb213ddf000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb213fde000, 28672, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x113000) = 0x7fb213fde000
mmap(0x7fb213fe5000, 8, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb213fe5000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libip4tc.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300\25\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=27088, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2122304, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb213ac4000
mprotect(0x7fb213aca000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb213cc9000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5000) = 0x7fb213cc9000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libseccomp.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200L\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=309456, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2404592, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb213878000
mprotect(0x7fb2138ab000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb213aaa000, 106496, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x32000) = 0x7fb213aaa000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20b\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=154832, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2259152, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb213650000
mprotect(0x7fb213675000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb213874000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x24000) = 0x7fb213874000
mmap(0x7fb213876000, 6352, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb213876000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0+\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=206872, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2302000, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb21341d000
mprotect(0x7fb21344f000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb21364e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x31000) = 0x7fb21364e000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340(\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=153984, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2248968, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb2131f7000
mprotect(0x7fb21321b000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb21341b000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x24000) = 0x7fb21341b000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240\35\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=112672, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb215291000
mmap(NULL, 2207840, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb212fdb000
mprotect(0x7fb212ff6000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb2131f5000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1a000) = 0x7fb2131f5000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000\230\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=311720, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2411776, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb212d8e000
mprotect(0x7fb212dd5000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb212fd5000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x47000) = 0x7fb212fd5000
mmap(0x7fb212fda000, 3328, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb212fda000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000b\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=144976, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2221184, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb212b6f000
mprotect(0x7fb212b89000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb212d88000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19000) = 0x7fb212d88000
mmap(0x7fb212d8a000, 13440, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb212d8a000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260\20\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=18680, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2113752, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb21296a000
mprotect(0x7fb21296e000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb212b6d000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7fb212b6d000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@\26\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=27112, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2122112, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb212763000
mprotect(0x7fb212769000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb212968000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5000) = 0x7fb212968000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdevmapper.so.1.02.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\266\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=432640, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2532048, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb2124f8000
mprotect(0x7fb21255e000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb21275d000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x65000) = 0x7fb21275d000
mmap(0x7fb212762000, 720, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb212762000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libargon2.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240\r\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=34872, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb21528f000
mmap(NULL, 2130080, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb2122ef000
mprotect(0x7fb2122f7000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb2124f6000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x7000) = 0x7fb2124f6000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-c.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P'\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=43304, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2138456, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb2120e4000
mprotect(0x7fb2120ee000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb2122ed000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x9000) = 0x7fb2122ed000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340+\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=84032, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2179304, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb211ecf000
mprotect(0x7fb211ee3000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb2120e2000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x13000) = 0x7fb2120e2000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \25\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=464824, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2560264, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb211c5d000
mprotect(0x7fb211ccd000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb211ecd000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x70000) = 0x7fb211ecd000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14560, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109712, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb211a59000
mprotect(0x7fb211a5c000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb211c5b000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fb211c5b000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\3008\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=121016, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb21528d000
mmap(NULL, 2218280, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb21183b000
mprotect(0x7fb211858000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb211a57000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c000) = 0x7fb211a57000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200\272\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1700792, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3789144, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb21149d000
mprotect(0x7fb21163a000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb211839000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19c000) = 0x7fb211839000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb21528b000
mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb215288000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fb215288940) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb215070000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb211839000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb212d88000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb214846000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb211a57000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb211c5b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb211ecd000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb2120e2000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb2122ed000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb2124f6000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb213874000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb21275d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb212968000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb212b6d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb212fd5000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb2131f5000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb21341b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb21364e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb213aaa000, 102400, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb213cc9000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb213fde000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb21422f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb214438000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb21463e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb214bfc000, 565248, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x562bdd4dd000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb2152a1000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fb215297000, 39569)           = 0
set_tid_address(0x7fb215288c10)         = 1612
set_robust_list(0x7fb215288c20, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0x7fb212b74cb0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7fb212b81890}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x7fb212b74d50, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7fb212b81890}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x562bdd747000
brk(0x562bdd768000)                     = 0x562bdd768000
statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", 0x7fffde187670) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statfs("/selinux", 0x7fffde187670)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\trootfs\nnodev\tt"..., 1024) = 474
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/selinux/config", F_OK)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1683056, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1683056, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb2150ed000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2995, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2995
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=252, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 252, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb2152a0000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=26376, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 26376, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x7fb215299000
close(3)                                = 0
futex(0x7fb215075a08, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_MEASUREMENT", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=23, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 23, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb215298000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_TELEPHONE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=47, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 47, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb215297000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_ADDRESS", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=131, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 131, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb2150ec000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_NAME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=62, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 62, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb2150eb000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_PAPER", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=34, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 34, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb2150ea000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/SYS_LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=48, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 48, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb2150e9000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=270, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 270, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb2150e8000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1516558, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1516558, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb21132a000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_TIME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3360, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3360, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb2150e7000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=50, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 50, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb2150e6000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=199772, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 199772, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb2150b5000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/stat", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, "1612 (hostnamectl) R 1610 1610 1"..., 1024) = 312
close(3)                                = 0
getpid()                                = 1612
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
getsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [212992], [4]) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUFFORCE, [8388608], 4) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [8388608], 4) = 0
getsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [212992], [4]) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUFFORCE, [8388608], 4) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [8388608], 4) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket"}, 29) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/C.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/C/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/C.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/C.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/C/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
writev(2, [{iov_base="Failed to create bus connection:"..., iov_len=58}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 2Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory
) = 59
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: Thanks for moving the question over from stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the core, the problem is that `hostnamectl` is a systemd utility, which acts on the systemd-hostnamed.service.  WSL doesn't currently provide support for systemd.

Also, WSL sets the hostname to the name of the Windows computer hosting the instance.  While you can change it by changing the Windows hostname (`Control Panel` -> `System` -> `See the name of this computer` -> `Change Settings`), you can't change the WSL hostname itself.

What's your ultimate goal with changing the hostname, other than just following the tutorial you linked?  Perhaps there is a better solution (e.g. changing the prompt).

Comment: I actually came to the tutorial I linked from another pluralsight tutorial on setting up kubernetes. Since pluralsight is blocked by a paywall, I'll list out what I'm supposed to run.


#   1. 3 VMs Ubuntu 16.04.5 or 18.04.1.0, 1 master, 3 nodes.
#   2. Static IPs on individual VMs
#   3. /etc/hosts hosts file includes name to IP mappings for VMs
#   4. Swap is disabled
#   5. Take snapshots prior to installations, this way you can install 
#       and revert to snapshot if needed

ssh aen@c1-master1

Comment: I think you are going to find it difficult to complete that Kubernetes tutorial using WSL2.  WSL2 instances run as a NAT'd VM behind a virtual NIC that Windows provides, and that NIC address changes on every restart (and you can't control it easily).  I'd probably recommend using something like VirtualBox instead, where you have more control over the network.  If you have Windows 10 Professional or higher, you could also use Hyper-V (which is actually what WSL2 uses behind-the-scenes) to give you more control.

Comment: I actually have access to both VirtualBox and Hyper -V as well as another tutorial tailed just for WSL2. https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/05/21/wsl-docker-kubernetes-on-the-windows-desktop/

I'll try to go down the Hyper-V path for now and hopefully it will permit use of things like
hostnamectl